# Unstable NIC: how to troubleshoot?

Tags: debian, network-interface

I have a network connection that is unstable - I think it must be from the switch to the server, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. This is the setup:

The switch is an N5860-48SC, 48-Port Ethernet L3 Data Center Switch, 48 x 10Gb SFP+, with 8 x 100Gb QSFP28 - the server is connected to one of the 100G ports with a fibre cable. The reason I think it must be from that port down to the server is that there are no problems with any of the other systems that are connected to the 10G ports with copper.

The server is an Intel based server with a 100G NIC - lspci and ethtool show:

```
# lspci
...
51:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller E810-C for QSFP (rev 02)
51:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller E810-C for QSFP (rev 02)
...
# ethtool ens4f0
Settings for ens4f0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
                                50000baseCR2/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
                                50000baseSR2/Full
                                100000baseSR2/Full
                                100000baseCR2/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: None
        Advertised link modes:  25000baseSR/Full
                                50000baseCR2/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: None
        Speed: 100000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Pinging from another system (over 1G NIC) is odd- sometimes it is unreachable, sometimes the time is really big:

```
...
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=560 ttl=64 time=0.297 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=561 ttl=64 time=0.284 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=562 ttl=64 time=0.231 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=563 ttl=64 time=0.280 ms
From 192.168.50.29 (192.168.50.29) icmp_seq=567 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.50.29 (192.168.50.29) icmp_seq=568 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.50.29 (192.168.50.29) icmp_seq=569 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=570 ttl=64 time=0.423 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=571 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms
...
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=591 ttl=64 time=0.298 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=592 ttl=64 time=0.267 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=598 ttl=64 time=1020 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=599 ttl=64 time=0.337 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=600 ttl=64 time=0.260 ms
...
```

Finally, /var/log/messages:

```
# cat messages
Aug 28 00:10:21 knox rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2102.0" x-pid="785" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Aug 29 11:25:09 knox kernel: [2160313.695273] ice 0000:51:00.0 ens4f0: NIC Link is Down
Aug 29 11:25:09 knox kernel: [2160313.791123] ice 0000:51:00.0 ens4f0: NIC Link is up 100 Gbps Full Duplex, Requested FEC: RS-FEC, Negotiated FEC: RS-FEC, Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False, Flow Control: None
Aug 29 14:28:17 knox kernel: [2171301.703959] ice 0000:51:00.0 ens4f0: NIC Link is Down
Aug 29 14:28:17 knox kernel: [2171301.808407] ice 0000:51:00.0 ens4f0: NIC Link is up 100 Gbps Full Duplex, Requested FEC: RS-FEC, Negotiated FEC: RS-FEC, Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False, Flow Control: None
Aug 31 21:51:47 knox kernel: [2370711.058542] ice 0000:51:00.0 ens4f0: NIC Link is Down
Aug 31 21:51:47 knox kernel: [2370711.155567] ice 0000:51:00.0 ens4f0: NIC Link is up 100 Gbps Full Duplex, Requested FEC: RS-FEC, Negotiated FEC: RS-FEC, Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False, Flow Control: None
```

Those may not be relevant to the problem, but it certainly isn't something I've done manually.

---***EDIT***---

Another thing I just noticed - packets seem to be quietly lost, note the jump in sequence numbers from 7 to 16 and 24 to 30:

```
# ping knox
PING knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.374 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.233 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.267 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.234 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.277 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.234 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.224 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=0.224 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=0.312 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=0.291 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=0.282 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=0.243 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=0.274 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=0.260 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=31 ttl=64 time=0.497 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=32 ttl=64 time=0.280 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=33 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=0.283 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=0.297 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
```

Comment: Do `ethtool -S ens4f0` and `ethtool --phy-statistics ens4f0` indicate anything noteworthy?

Comment: I once observed similar problems caused by a faulty SFP module. Packets were getting lost, link sometimes went down and up again. Is replacing components (modules, NICs, the switch, ultimately the cable) one by one an option? You won't find out *why* something is not working, but *what*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thank you to those who kindly offered to help - it spurred me on to doing some deeper debugging. I ran `dmidecode` quite a few times, and finally realised the problem: the card was inserted into a PCIe 3.0 slot, which only delivers something like 63 Gbps, so of course a NIC that runs at 100 Gbps will have trouble. When I moved it to the only PCIe 4.0 socket, at first I couldn't detect any transceivers; this was fixed by upgrading the BIOS and BMC firmware.

The final problem is that only one of the modules is active; to activate it, I will have to set up PCIe bifurcation in the BIOS for that slot - however, since the 100 Gbps is far more than what the RAID card supports (12 Gbps), I can already saturate the disk array over the network, so that can wait.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

1. Check your configuration using systemd-networkd (the system that translate ifupdown).

   networkctl -a status

Analise if it is what you intended (that command is part of systemd-networkd). If it is not exactly what you intended scripting /etc/network/interfaces, then consider using systemd directly instead ifupdown.

2. Check for failed services:

   systemctl --type=service --state=failed
3. If you use /etc/network/interfaces and you have debian 11 then you probably have newer systemd fighting (translating) your older style configuration. In that case move /etc/network/interfaces to /etc/network/interfaces.save end configure your network using systemd. Create:

   /etc/systemd/network/10-mynet1.network

   /etc/systemd/network/20-mynet2.network

   .....

The syntax for systemd-networkd is different then in interfaces.

There are old and new networking system in debian 11.x. This systems are working only in simplest situation on my debian 11.5 minimal server installation. I spend 5 days fiting ifupdown with unexplained behaviors. I moved to systemd and all as expected after 1h.

Regards,
Bogdan