# Intel NIC E810-C with unstable connection - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: debian, network-interface

This is in continuation of my previous question, [Unstable NIC: how to troubleshoot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/715885/unstable-nic-how-to-troubleshoot). The NIC is:

```
# networkctl -a status
...
● 4: ens6f0                                                                                             
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: n/a
                          Type: ether
                         State: n/a (unmanaged)
             Alternative Names: enp24s0f0
                          Path: pci-0000:18:00.0
                        Driver: ice
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Controller E810-C for QSFP (Ethernet Network Adapter E810-C-Q2)
                    HW Address: 64:9d:99:ff:fe:c0 (FS COM INC)
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9702)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: eui64
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 320/320
              Auto negotiation: no
                         Speed: 100Gbps
                        Duplex: full
                          Port: fibre
                       Address: 192.168.50.7
                                fe80::669d:99ff:feff:fec0
                       Gateway: 192.168.50.1 (TP-LINK TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD.)
Failed to query link DHCP leases: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service not found.
```

The OS is:

```
# cat /etc/*release*
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

And the motherboard is:

```
# dmidecode -t baseboard
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Supermicro
        Product Name: X12SPL-F
        Version: 2.00
        Serial Number: ZM224S007191
        Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis: Part Component
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0
```

The NIC is in the only 16 lane slot:

```
Handle 0x000F, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: CPU SLOT6 PCI-E 4.0 X16
        Type: x16 PCI Express 4 x16
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Long
        ID: 6
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
        Bus Address: 0000:18:00.0
```

The problem I have is that the NIC keeps dropping, for unknown reasons, and I don't know how to dig deeper into it. So far, all I have is this from `dmesg`:

```
# dmesg | grep 0000:18:00.0

[    0.754043] pci 0000:18:00.0: [8086:1592] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.754056] pci 0000:18:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x201ffa000000-0x201ffbffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.754070] pci 0000:18:00.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0x201ffe010000-0x201ffe01ffff 64bit pref]
[    0.754080] pci 0000:18:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xbb600000-0xbb6fffff pref]
[    0.754166] pci 0000:18:00.0: reg 0x184: [mem 0x201ffd000000-0x201ffd01ffff 64bit pref]
[    0.754168] pci 0000:18:00.0: VF(n) BAR0 space: [mem 0x201ffd000000-0x201ffdffffff 64bit pref] (contains BAR0 for 128 VFs)
[    0.754179] pci 0000:18:00.0: reg 0x190: [mem 0x201ffe220000-0x201ffe223fff 64bit pref]
[    0.754180] pci 0000:18:00.0: VF(n) BAR3 space: [mem 0x201ffe220000-0x201ffe41ffff 64bit pref] (contains BAR3 for 128 VFs)
[    0.754429] pci 0000:18:00.0: 126.016 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 8.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link at 0000:17:02.0 (capable of 252.048 Gb/s with 16.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link)
[    0.800984] pci 0000:18:00.0: CLS mismatch (64 != 32), using 64 bytes
[    1.369098] pci 0000:18:00.0: Adding to iommu group 31
[    1.819150] ice 0000:18:00.0: firmware: failed to load intel/ice/ddp/ice-e20070ffffd99fd0.pkg (-2)
[    1.819589] ice 0000:18:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ice/ddp/ice.pkg
[    2.140744] ice 0000:18:00.0: The DDP package was successfully loaded: ICE OS Default Package version 1.3.30.0
[    2.211858] ice 0000:18:00.0: PTP init successful
[    2.616387] ice 0000:18:00.0: DCB is enabled in the hardware, max number of TCs supported on this port are 8
[    2.616387] ice 0000:18:00.0: FW LLDP is disabled, DCBx/LLDP in SW mode.
[    2.616492] ice 0000:18:00.0: Commit DCB Configuration to the hardware
[    2.618380] ice 0000:18:00.0: 126.016 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 8.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link at 0000:17:02.0 (capable of 252.048 Gb/s with 16.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link)
[    2.621272] ice 0000:18:00.0 eth0: A parallel fault was detected.
[    2.621365] ice 0000:18:00.0 eth0: Possible Solution: Check link partner connection and configuration.
[    2.621513] ice 0000:18:00.0 eth0: Port Number: 1.
[    3.331319] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: renamed from eth0
[ 1052.057728] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: NIC Link is up 100 Gbps Full Duplex, Requested FEC: RS-FEC, Negotiated FEC: RS-FEC, Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False, Flow Control: None
[2304065.370537] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: NIC Link is Down
[2304065.470757] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: NIC Link is up 100 Gbps Full Duplex, Requested FEC: RS-FEC, Negotiated FEC: RS-FEC, Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False, Flow Control: None
[6567288.755539] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: Changing Rx descriptor count from 2048 to 8160
[10043828.294404] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: NIC Link is Down
[10043828.394033] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: NIC Link is up 100 Gbps Full Duplex, Requested FEC: RS-FEC, Negotiated FEC: RS-FEC, Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False, Flow Control: None
[10198013.280727] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: NIC Link is Down
[10198013.381243] ice 0000:18:00.0 ens6f0: NIC Link is up 100 Gbps Full Duplex, Requested FEC: RS-FEC, Negotiated FEC: RS-FEC, Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False, Flow Control: None
```

But I'm not convinced this the real problem - it doesn't seem to happen often enough to explain the problems I see, and it comes back up in less than a second. The problems do seem to be related to connections over the network, like:

```
root@pluto:/home/comind# ping knox
PING knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.476 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.542 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.521 ms
...
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=0.544 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=0.554 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=34 ttl=64 time=0.539 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=0.402 ms
64 bytes from knox.comind.io (192.168.50.7): icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=0.539 ms
...
```

The breaks (like `icmp_sec=27` to `icmp_sec=34` seem to be around 7 sec in length every time, and happen quite often. I see something similar with terminal sessions - keyboard input seems to stop for a number of seconds, then show up on the terminal; sometimes characters are lost. Finally, the NFS share from that server is affected by the same delays.

The NFS service is provided by ganesha V3.4, and log contains a number of lines like:

```
13/01/2023 01:09:46 : epoch 63a6c5e3 : knox : ganesha.nfsd-3365103[svc_946] rpc :TIRPC :EVENT :svc_ioq_flushv: 0x7fc37422f1b0 fd 10798 msg_iov 0x7fc2da2e0f60 sendmsg remaining 112 result -1 error Broken pipe (32)
13/01/2023 06:26:54 : epoch 63a6c5e3 : knox : ganesha.nfsd-3365103[svc_887] rpc :TIRPC :EVENT :svc_ioq_flushv: 0x7fc2190609f0 fd 10386 msg_iov 0x7fc447406f60 sendmsg remaining 112 result -1 error Broken pipe (32)
13/01/2023 08:06:33 : epoch 63a6c5e3 : knox : ganesha.nfsd-3365103[svc_967] rpc :TIRPC :EVENT :svc_ioq_flushv: 0x7fc1f42aec90 fd 10387 msg_iov 0x7fc2d8ac8f60 sendmsg remaining 112 result -1 error Broken pipe (32)
13/01/2023 08:36:01 : epoch 63a6c5e3 : knox : ganesha.nfsd-3365103[svc_967] rpc :TIRPC :EVENT :svc_ioq_flushv: 0x7fc11c5ee4c0 fd 10388 msg_iov 0x7fc2d8ac8f60 sendmsg remaining 112 result -1 error Broken pipe (32)
13/01/2023 08:38:04 : epoch 63a6c5e3 : knox : ganesha.nfsd-3365103[svc_1032] rpc :TIRPC :EVENT :svc_ioq_flushv: 0x7fc134b4f480 fd 10394 msg_iov 0x7fc38cde1f60 sendmsg remaining 112 result -1 error Broken pipe (32)
13/01/2023 10:55:53 : epoch 63a6c5e3 : knox : ganesha.nfsd-3365103[svc_1032] rpc :TIRPC :EVENT :svc_vc_wait: 0x7fc1e8074320 fd 10603 recv errno 104 (will set dead)
```

Again, there aren't enough errors in the log to explain the frequent delays.

To me it seems clear that this is network issue - the server is connected to a switch from FS: `N5860-48SC`, but unfortunately I don't know enough about troubleshooting things on the switch. I would appreciate any help, insight or suggestions for how to attack this issue.

Comment: Does using kernel 6.1.5 help?

Comment: not sure - it might, but upgrading the kernel will require a reboot, which will have to be planned well in advance.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Your suggestion is good, and I am going to try it, but I'd really like to also be able to dig deeper into the problem of failing connections, so if anybody has some insight to offer, that is still of interest.

Comment: Debian 11 has quite a date kernel, your HW is brand new. In the world of Linux that normally means you must run the latest kernel 'cause it's where all the development is going on and code is fixed.

Comment: Link flapping and _Autoneg Advertised: Off, Autoneg Negotiated: False_ - I'd start by verifying that both the NIC and the switch port are set to autonegotiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem: dust in the optics. Somehow, someone (not mentioning names, but it was someone very close to me!) had managed to pull out the fibre cable and reinserting it without cleaning the optics - what an idiot. After a careful cleaning, everything works perfectly. We live and learn.

Answer (score 2):

When there is an unstable link, especially on fiber, one very good indicator is if you're getting a local fault or a remote fault.

Look at the counters in the command:

```
ethtool -S ens6f0
```

and see something like this:

```
$ ethtool -S ens259f0 |grep fault
     mac_local_faults.nic: 0
     mac_remote_faults.nic: 0
```

If there is nothing there, please grab the output from

```
ethtool -m ens6f0
ethtool -S ens6f0
ethtool -i ens6f0
devlink dev info
```

And double check you are running the latest firmware / NVM image available.

And a last place to look when troubleshooting, is the switch logs itself, to see if it indicates whether you're getting a local (switch side) or remote (E810 side) fault.

If the E810 is showing local faults the troubleshooting should lead you to contact support with some of the information gathered above. There is a lot that could be wrong but following some of the basic steps above should help isolate some.

Comment: Changed my response to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When doing `ethtool -m`, check for any alarms and RX/TX power levels are within range, for range you can look at the alarms threshold.

The threshold can vary from different SFP modules.